# Confusing and sporadic rheem ac unit issue

Tags: hvac

I'm going to ask this question because I'm out of options and so are the technicians. Last summer, after having a blower motor replaced, the next day I started having trouble with my ac unit. Sporadically, it will start to make a grinding noise almost like a garbage disposal sound for 15 minutes, the compressor with turn off and the fan will run for 15 minutes, and then the compressor will re-engage. The entire unit was replaced and also a start capacitor was put on for low voltage. It worked great for two month before shutting down for the winter. I started it this year and the same problem is back. Any suggestions ? I have had about 15 visits from technicians and everyone is stumped. The unit can run great for days and then the issue happens and there is no telling when it will occur again. Also this is a rheem unit. Prior to the replacement unit and blower motor replacement  I had the exact same unit installed when the house was purchased  and it worked great for 4 years.

Comment: Almost sounds like there is something inside the system that should not be there.  Every so often it gets sucked in and touches/jams, before being kicked away again.

Comment: do you hear the noise after the compressor kicks off and the fan is still running?

Comment: When you say blower that means the motor in the air handler, the motor in the outside unit is a fan. If the fan was what was changed is the fan spinning up and staying at speed? When you hear the growing what is the fan doing? A capacitor will help a motor start but doesn't affect the ac voltage it creates a phase shift. I would be looking for loose or bad connections in the contactor or in the disconnect bad connections will create a voltage drop. I would be looking at the compressor a 240v system the fan only draws about 3 amps but the compressor 20-40 amps depending on how many ton system.

Comment: Note I recently went to a company office where a fan motor had been replaced the fan motor was stopping and starting every 30 seconds and not cooling properly. What I found was the new motor was a different model and was not properly wired causing it to draw enough to trip its thermal safety. I fixed this but noticed the system surging and having a hard time getting to speed. I found one of the legs in the disconnect loose so when the high load of the compressor+fan starting it did drop the voltage after replacing the melted wire insulation and tighten things worked fine it can be a loose wire

Answer (score 0):

Grinding and sometimes vibrations from locked rotor of an electric motor can sound like grinding.  Both are bad and could be caused as crip659 suggests, by something caught in the coolant loop.  If your current motor unit isn't toast already, I'd suggest having your whole coolant loop drained, strained, filtered, high pressure/ solvent washed to be absolutely sure there isn't something awful like metal filings or even just insoluble crud. If the motor is rated for continuous duty, you could run some known, filtered, clean load through it for a time to confirm any damage isn't permanent.

If you still have the old motor, you could also take it apart to get an idea of what killed it.

A single phase motor failing to start can make a vibraty grinding noise before the overcurrent/ overload protection kicks in.  If that's what you're hearing it could easily be caused by a clog.  Compressor motors allow almost no backflow, so once the working fluid is compressed, it would be like pushing against a concrete wall.  The last motor I saw exhibit this behaviour was on my furnace fan and it was a rather old motor though.